# Bind existing Array to tableView IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

i have an array that contains 5 items when i debugging but when i try to bind them to a tableview the tableview is empty without error.
It works if a do an array manually and initwithobjects but i already have an array.

After this my array have 5 objects

```
array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

The problem is the part where i try to init the array.

If i do this my array is null after.

```
 array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

and if i do this my array still have 5 object but not loaded into table

```
array = [array init];
```

Thanks for your help

All Code

```
NSArray *array;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSString *request = [NSString stringWithFormat:

                         @"http://192.168.99.99/IBookService.svc/GetBooksNames"];

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:

                  [request stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];

    if(!error)

    {

        array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
        array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    }

    _tblCustomers.dataSource = self;
    _tblCustomers.delegate = self;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [array count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *identity = @"custTbl";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identity];

    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:identity];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;

}
```

Comment: Add Array in .h file like `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray * array;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add object to the array and after that you allocate it (clear it). Do it other way around:

```
    if(!error)

    {
        array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently array is deallocated when you leave viewDidLoad method. You should make array a member of class to avoid this. For example you can add following

```
{
    NSArray *array;
}
```

after line

```
@implementation Your_class_name_here
```

And delete your current line

```
NSArray *array;
```

Comment: thank you i think i done that but it was not clear 
    @implementation ViewController
    NSArray *array;

- (void)viewDidLoad